# Deal with timedelta () and datetime.now

Tags: python, django, django-models, timedelta

I'd like to set `timedelta` for a data model

```
class ActivateCode(models.Model):
    """ """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_expired = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now + timedelta(days=1))
```

It seem not a proper solution because `datetime.now` is not called but `timedetla(days=1)` is invoked.

How to deal with such an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: we can **create a function** to calculate the next day.

We can not add a function with a `timedelta(..)` object, since nor the function has an `__add__` method, nor a `timedelta` object has a `__radd__` method to add functions and `timedelta`s together, therefore Python/Django can not construct a new function with this syntax.

We can however solve this problem by creating a function that calculates the default time:

```
def tomorrow():
    return datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)

class ActivateCode(models.Model):
    """ """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_expired = models.DateTimeField(default=tomorrow)
```

We here do *not* invoke the function we set as `default=...`, we only pass a reference to our `tomorrow` function, such that if Django creates a new object, it will call the `tomorrow(..)` function, and thus calcuate exactly the next day.